# Stripping content from a website to my website

Tags: javascript, html, yql

I am trying to make a website that stream from a wiki page and take the content down into my page.

Before anyone saying it is illegal to scrape a website, mind you this is a wiki site, and under each page of that site, there is:

> Content is available under Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 3.0 Unported.

Meaning I am free to use and REUSE the info that is provided to me.

This is the wiki page: http://wiki.mabinogiworld.com/

Basically I am trying to make a website to take the server online status table directly and put it into my webpage, but at the same time I want to keep it updated, so it have to re-get the table next time the webpage is refreshed.

With this, I faced the cross domain issue and found something related to YQL that seems to be able to help me, but I still cant figure it out.

This is what I did so far:

```
YUI().use("yql", function (Y) 
{
    var query = 'SELECT * FROM html WHERE url="http://wiki.mabinogiworld.com/" and xpath="//div/table"';

    Y.YQL(query, function(results) 
    {
        var temp;
        var size = 0;
        temp = results.query.results.table;
        size = temp.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        {
            //Loop through the result and find the exact table I want
        }
    }
}
```

With the above code (the loop is too messy that I cut it out) I am able to get the exact table I want with all the sub columns and rows, but it is returned in a structure that I have no idea how to translate back into HTML.

What can I do to get the table from the wiki page and put it onto my webpage? And what is the variable type of "results" anyways? I cant seems to use it in any ways other than access.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was downvoted: what needs to be improved here, specifically?

Comment: You should realize that web scraping can be illegal. Make sure you cover all of you legal bases with a lot of research.

Comment: The site is a wiki site, I dont see any issue using any info that is avaliable to me on that webpage.

Comment: "I am free to use the info that is provided to me." So long as your site follows all of the guidelines for using data under that license. You might be in the clear, but it will take you a little bit of time to do all of the research to make sure your bases are covered. See http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/

Comment: For example, that license says "Share Alike — If you alter, transform, or build upon this work, you may distribute the resulting work only under the same or similar license to this one."

Comment: Did you check it out before you down voted me? I stated I can, because it clearly said I am free to REUSE the page, it is written there. Can you find me a phrase that says otherwise that come from the policy?

Comment: Dude, I didn't downvote you. I'm just saying that you should be sure and it's not a trivial process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something that is posted here: [YQL JSON script not returning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147705/yql-json-script-not-returning)

Basically it makes AJAX possible with help of YQL

Source: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-cross-domain-ajax-request-with-yql-and-jquery/

---

Well, if you really want to keep the formatting and the style of the table, make your own table, and then put your own style onto it, and then extract info out of YQL and start populating the table. That way it be done with your method. YQL is really useful, I started playing with it a bit and find it very powerful.

Not sure if that would violate the copyright rules or not though, since you are indeed reusing the data in your own format.

Comment: The solution works, but it did not strip the entire HTML, it left out some of the styling attributes which made the table looks all weird.

Comment: YQL will not strip out the entire HTML with CSS, some of the style just wont return from the query. Use their console to see, I am sure the return itself already got rid of those before presenting to you.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing in the end, so I'll choose your answer.

Answer (score 0):

### YQL Solution

First off, your XPath query is way too broad. Looking at the wiki page's source, I came up with this:

```
//div[@id='mw-content-text']/table//table[@class='center']
```

Unfortunately, the table that you want doesn't have an ID on it, so selecting tables with a `center` class was the best I could do. This returns 5 different tables; you want the first one. I tried to use the "first element" predicate (`table[@class='center'][1]`), but that didn't seem to do anything. Notice that the XML in the `<results>` element is straight XHTML that you could dump into your page. (That's assuming that you're requesting the results as XML, not JSON)

I found [Yahoo's YQL Console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url%3D%22http%3A//wiki.mabinogiworld.com/%22%20and%20xpath%3D%22//div%5B@id%3D%27mw-content-text%27%5D/table//table%5B@class%3D%27center%27%5D%5B1%5D%22) really helpful. It allows you to fine tune your query before trying to incorporate it with Javascript to parse the results.

---

### jQuery Solution

This isn't the optimal solution, but it circumvents the need to parse XML in Javascript or convert JSON to HTML. You can do an AJAX call to get the HTML and then strip out everything besides the table:

```
var scrapeUrl = 'www.example.com';
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: scrapeUrl,
  success(html) {
    var $scrapedElement = $(html).find("h1");
    $("#scrapedDataDiv").html($scrapedElement);
  },
  error() {
    alert("Problem getting table");
  }
});
```

In this example, the code downloads the page at `www.example.com` and scrapes out all of the `h1` tags, thanks to jQuery's handy selectors. The `h1` tags are then place in a `div` with the id of `scrapedDataDiv`.

Obviously, you still have to deal with XSS/Same Origin issues. You can do this by setting up a proxy on your server.

Comment: You can't just use AJAX to get arbitrary pages.  You need to obey the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: Right, but you could set up a proxy on your server for the AJAX call. That's basically what YQL does. If the OP wants a strictly YUI/YQL, I'll gladly delete my answer.

Comment: I welcome any answers, but I dont see any ways of setting up a proxy locally... Even with php, file_get_contents is also blocked by cross domain issue

Comment: I'm not a PHP user, but it seems like PHP's [curl](http://us2.php.net/curl) library does this.

Comment: For some reason the result I got from the query is not string, it is actually some object that I tried forever to find out what type is it and how to manipulate it. I realized from the console that YQL does not return full HTML since it left out some of the stylings... Maybe YQL isnt the best solution afterall... Going to try ajax!

Comment: The style issues probably stem from the fact that you're getting the table's HTML, but the table is styled via stylesheets in the `<head>` portion of the page. You would have to expand your code to scrape the CSS as well, which could be a big pain.